# z-index of core-animated-pages ignored

Tags: polymer

Why is my z-index being ignored?

```
<core-drawer-panel>
                        <div drawer>
                                Test
                        </div>
                        <div main>
                            <core-icon-button core-drawer-toggle icon="menu" style="z-index:1000 !important;"></core-icon-button>
                            <my-element style="z-index:-1000 !important;"></my-element>
                        </div>
</core-drawer-panel>
```

my-element has `<core-animated-pages fit>` and it does not care at all about the z-index? Its stays on top all the time?

EDIT:

`z-index:1000 !important` does not work.

But in `my-element` I can do this `<core-animated-pages fit selected="{{subPage}}" style="overflow:auto; z-index:-1;">` but then the overflow does not work meaning I see a scroll bar but it does not scroll?

(https://github.com/Polymer/core-animated-pages/issues/36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` as well as a z-index on elements. If you don't explicitly set a position, the z-index does not work (also for 'normal' HTML).